# Parametrized Path Boundary

Tags: real-analysis

For a piecewise smooth parametrized path $\gamma:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ and a continuous function $f:\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ where $\Gamma$ is the image of $\gamma$, show that

$ | \int_\Gamma f(s) ds | \leq Ml  $

where $M$ is such that $|f(p)| \leq M$ for all points $p$ on $\Gamma$ and $l$ is the arclength of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

You used the parameter $s$, which is usually reserved for arc-length. I'll assume that $s$ is not arc-length and is an arbitrary parameter. We first substitute $s = \gamma(t)$ to give:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\int_{\Gamma} f(s) \, \operatorname{d}\!s = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\, \gamma'(t) \, \operatorname{d}\!t
\end{array}

Next, we apply a standard result:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\left|\int_{\Gamma} f(s) \, \operatorname{d}\!s\right| &=& \left|\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\, \gamma'(t) \, \operatorname{d}\!t\right| \\
&\le& \int_a^b \left|f(\gamma(t))\, \gamma'(t)\right| \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\
&=&  \int_a^b \left|f(\gamma(t))\right| \, \left|\gamma'(t)\right| \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\
&\le&  \int_a^b M \, \left|\gamma'(t)\right| \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\
&=& M \int_a^b \left|\gamma'(t)\right| \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\
&=& M\ell
\end{array}